# Trouble with Wix developer tools

Tags: java, api, mobile, velo

I am using a wix page as a place to send my users to complete an ID verification through Veriff. However, if my users open the website on their phone, when prompted to allow camera access, they grant access but the Veriff form never starts. When I add the code Veriff tells me to add, I get an error on Wix stating "cannot use JSX unless the jsx flag is provided. I've included a screenshot of what I see when I'm working.

[Screenshot of Wix editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVLMy.jpg)

```
$w.onReady(function () {
<>
  <script src='https://cdn.veriff.me/sdk/js/1.1/veriff.min.js'</script>
 <script src='https://cdn.veriff.me/incontext/js/v1/veriff.js'</script>

<div id='veriff-root'></div>
<script>
const veriff = Veriff({
host: '*************',
apiKey: '************',
parentId: 'veriff-root',
onSession: function(err, response) {
  window.veriffSDK.createVeriffFrame({ url: response.verification.url });
}
});
veriff.setParams({
person: {
  givenName: ' ',
  lastName: ' '
}
});
veriff.mount({
formLabel: {
  vendorData: 'Email'
}
});
</script> </>

});
```

Answer (score 0):

External scripts can be loaded using the iFrame Component or Wix Custom Element (Web Component)

HTML Component: https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/$w/htmlcomponent
Custom Element: https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/$w/customelement